# Storage Terminology in Containers - What is the difference between Disk vs Volume vs Mount

Tags: storage

When it comes to storage, especially in the world containers, we are using terms like

- Volume
- Mount
- Disk
- Directory

And probably others too. What is the difference between these terms and when should I use one vs the other?

Comment: [Differences between volume, partition and drive - Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/87300/117037)

Comment: "[Mount](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_(computing))" is a verb in this context, no? Do you mean "mount point"?